# Apply condition throughout multiple python arrays

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a number of arrays of same length:

```
a = [3,7,5,2,7]
b = [3,4,1,6,8]
c = [2,3,7,8,3]
d = [1,3,5,6,4]
e = [2,6,5,1,7]
```

My condition is x > 2. What I need is a final array checking if the condition applies for every position of all arrays.

The result would be:

```
[False, True, False, False, True]
```

Or even better:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Sorry if this is simple, I searched a  long time but only found related topics but none exactly answering this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack those `1D` input arrays as rows of a `2D` array with [`np.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html), perform the comparison and then use [`np.all`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) along the first axis. Thus, the implementation would be -

```
(np.vstack((a,b,c,d,e))>2).all(axis=0)
```

Sample run -

```
>>> np.vstack((a,b,c,d,e)) # Stack as a 2D array
array([[3, 7, 5, 2, 7],
       [3, 4, 1, 6, 8],
       [2, 3, 7, 8, 3],
       [1, 3, 5, 6, 4],
       [2, 6, 5, 1, 7]])
>>> np.vstack((a,b,c,d,e))>2
array([[ True,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> (np.vstack((a,b,c,d,e))>2).all(axis=0)
array([False,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```